# Is there a way to make WPF application less "ugly" in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

So, I just switched to Windows 10 and I noticed all my desktop `WPF` applications are noticeably "uglier" than they where on Win7/Win8.

I know this sounds subjective/pointless, but let me be more precise. Here's some examples of objective degradation of the UI's usability/clarity:

- Everything looks like Windows 95, all gray without shading of any kind, almost like there's a custom theme (or a default theme is missing or something)
- A lot of disabled elements do not get "grayed out" (see image below)
- Disabled `button`s do not get flattened (again, see image)
- `ListView` items are not highlighted on mouseOver
- `ProgressBar`s have the "blue segments" pre-XP look
- etc.

[image: example]

1. Is this "normal", i.e: is this the new default WPF theme?
2. If so, can I change it? It's really bad
3. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure it is a WPF app? It is looks like a Form Application

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari: it's a WPF 4.5 app, I developed it myself. I don't have a Win7 machine at the moment or I would show you how it looks there, it's totally different, loooks completely "native" on Win7.

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari even Winforms in Win7 looks better than that.

Comment: @Hopeless :) You right. it looks so ugly. I cant believe it. It is remind me Win 98 ;)

Comment: SImilar problems exist on Windows 8: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776142/wpf-built-in-theme-for-desktop-apps-on-windows-8-looks-substandard Official answer: "This is by design". Wierd...

Comment: @kol: indeed, it looks slightly worse in win8, but on win10 it's much uglier. What's the strategy here, make it worse at every release to discourage developers from using it? What's the alternative? Metro apps? Bah... I never though I'd see the day when native apps would look worse than Java's SWING/JavaFX apps, but it seems it has finally arrived.

Comment: Fortunately, the very essence of WPF is that you can redesign everything by creating your own styles and templates. Or, use someone else's UI library. Check out for example Mahapps at http://mahapps.com/

Comment: @kol: actually, your framework was one of the things I tried before posting this, but using it (at least the MetroWindow) looks all messed up (the window border, chrome and the minimize/close/expand icons in particular). I just assumed it wasn't yet adjusted for win10

Comment: This is not the normal (i.e. Aero2) theme for WPF, but the Classic one from Presentation.Classic.dll.

Comment: Creating a brand new WPF application from scratch and putting in a `ComboBox` and a `Button` shows that the default theme in Windows 10 matches the OS. It's nothing like what you get in your application. Please post a minimal application that actually produces the results you're asking about.

Comment: @hvd: thanks man, your comment actually pointed me in the right direction. I created a new app and I had the same problem as above, so I assumed it was something wrong with my OS installation, which it was. See my updated answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

After testing on another machine, turns out the problem had nothing to do with WPF or Windows.

Just DON'T apply any tweaks for win10 you find on the internet to restore the coloring on windows borders. It messes up the WPF theme engine.

Sorry for wasting your time guys.

<s>Well, I found out how to fix it (thanks to gix for pointing me in the right direction):</s>

First step: reference the `PresentationFramework.Aero2` assembly in your project
Second step: add the following to your `App.xaml`

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Aero2;component/themes/Aero2.NormalColor.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </Application.Resources>
```

Now it looks like it does in Windows 8. Note that you can also use `Aero` instead of `Aero2` if you want the Windows 7 look (also change the referenced dll of course!), but I think `Aero2` looks much more "native" on Win10.

**EDIT:** 
After further testing, turns out this is not 100% perfect, although it's close enough. For example: disabled text boxes are not grayed out, and `ListView`s seems to not be affected at all, they still look like they crawled out of Windows 98's ass... if anyone has a clue on how to make the Aero2 style stick to them as well it would be great